# How to get a random number between a float range?

Tags: python, random, floating-point

`random.randrange(start, stop)` only takes integer arguments. So how would I get a random number between two float values?

Comment: If you wanted numpy it's `np.random.uniform(start, stop)` or `np.random.uniform(start, stop, samples)` if you wanted multiple samples. Otherwise below answers are best.

Comment: Possible to generate uniform random between `[0 , 2*pi)`?

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

Use [random.uniform(a, b)](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.uniform(1.5, 1.9)
1.8733202628557872
```

Comment: could this theoretically produce 1.5 and 1.9? or would it only ever produce 1.50~1 and 1.89~?

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Short Answer: Yes. Longer answer: If you look at the documentation it states `Returns a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a` In other words the output `N` can equal either input `a` and `b`. In this case `1.5` and `1.9`.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using the `.uniform` function, but instead with either `.random` or `randrange`?

Comment: @DerryckDX `1.5 + random.random() * (1.9 - 1.5)` should do it, even though according to the specs this will never return exactly `1.9` (even in theory).

Comment: @Musixauce3000 it seems `uniform(a, b)` is implemented as `a + (b-a) * random()` and returns *a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding* https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/963eb0f4738456455b9bef7eb531b46805415208/Lib/random.py#L415

Comment: See a full document and example [here](https://pynative.com/python-get-random-float-numbers/)

Answer (score 146):

if you want generate a random float with N digits to the right of point, you can make this :

```
round(random.uniform(1,2), N)
```

the second argument is the number of decimals.

Answer (score 89):

`random.uniform(a, b)` appears to be what your looking for.  From the docs:

> Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform).

Comment: What if I want to generate an number as follow: Range of azimuth angle is 0 to 2*Pi radians excluding 2*pi viz., in mathematics range `[0, 2pi)`?

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar `random.random() * 2*math.pi`, as the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) says the random function _"Return[s] the next random floating point number in the range 0.0 <= X < 1.0"_

Answer (score 16):

Most commonly, you'd use:

```
import random
random.uniform(a, b) # range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on floating-point rounding
```

Python provides [other distributions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) if you need.

If you have `numpy` imported already, you can used its equivalent:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.uniform(a, b) # range [a, b)
```

Again, if you need another distribution, `numpy` provides the same distributions as python, as well as [many additional ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions).

Answer (score 16):

From my experience dealing with python, I can only say that the random function can help in generating random float numbers. Take the example below;

```
import random

# Random float number between range 15.5 to 80.5
print(random.uniform(15.5, 80.5))

# between 10 and 100
print(random.uniform(10, 100))
The random.uniform() function returns a random floating-point number between a given range in Python
```

The two sets of code generates random float numbers. You can try experimenting with it to give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get random floating point number between range n to m:

```
import random
random.uniform(n,m)
```

If you want to get a random float number up to x decimal places you can use this instead:

```
import random
round(random.uniform(n, m), x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For completness sake: If you use numpy, you can also call the [`uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.uniform.html#numpy.random.Generator.uniform) method on an instance of [random number generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator) (now the preferred way in numpy when dealing with random numbers).

```py
import numpy as np

seed = 42
low = 0.12
high = 3.45

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
rng.uniform(low, high)
```