# Python: Generate random number between x and y which is a multiple of 5

Tags: python, random

I've read the manual for pseudo-randomness in Python, and to my knowledge, you can only generate numbers up to a given maximum value, i.e. 0-1, 0-30, 0-1000, etc.  I want to:

- a) Generate a number between two ints, i.e. 5-55, and
- b) Only include multiples of 5 (or those ending in 5 or 0, if that's easier)

I've looked around, and I can't find anywhere that explains this.

Comment: Did you read http://docs.python.org/library/random.html? Scan down to the part titled "Functions for integers".

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Create an integer random between e.g. `1-11` and multiply it by `5`. Simple math.

```
import random
for x in range(20):
  print random.randint(1,11)*5,
print
```

produces e.g.

```
5 40 50 55 5 15 40 45 15 20 25 40 15 50 25 40 20 15 50 10
```

Comment: float: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range-python

Answer (score 69):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randrange(5,60,5)
```

should work in any Python >= 2.

Comment: While I feel this is the better answer, I would like to point out that this answer excludes 60 from being returned, which can be counterintuitive. I recommend using `random.randrage(5,55+1,5)` as a more clear way of doing this.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to do it all by yourself, you can use the [random.randrange](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) function.

For example `import random; print random.randrange(10, 25, 5)` prints a number that is between 10 and 25 (10 included, 25 excluded) and is a multiple of 5. So it would print 10, 15, or 20.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to generate a random nuber between 0-1 then strech it by multiplying,  and shifting it.
So yo would multiply by (x-y)  so the result is in the range of 0 to x-y,
Then add x and you get the random number between x and y.

To get a five multiplier use rounding. If this is unclear let me know and I'll add code snippets.

Comment: As anonymouse pointed out,  the use of in-range randomization is much cleaner.