# Random number that is divisible by N

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate a random number from range [a,b] that is dividsible by N (4 in my case).
I have the solution, but is there a better (more elegant) way to do it?

```
result = random.randint(a, b)
result = math.ceil(result / 4) * 4
```

Solutions from here:
[Python: Generate random number between x and y which is a multiple of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287167/python-generate-random-number-between-x-and-y-which-is-a-multiple-of-5)
doesn't answer my question since I'll have to implement something like:

```
random.randint(a, b) * 4;
```

I'll have to divide original range by 4 and it's less readable then my original solution

Comment: Your solution is wrong. For e.g. if a=1, b=15, your solution may give 16 which is wrong

Comment: "a number that divides by N" isn't legal English, and "a number that divides N" means the other thing. I think you mean **"a number that is divisible by N"**

Comment: @DYZ please see my comment regarding duplicate solution you've mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic solution and an example

```
import random

def divisible_random(a,b,n):
    if b-a < n:
      raise Exception('{} is too big'.format(n))
    result = random.randint(a, b)
    while result % n != 0:
      result = random.randint(a, b)
    return result
# get a random int in the range 2 - 12, the number is divisible by 3
print(divisible_random(2,12,3))
```

Comment: Simple and generic, thanks!

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this *can* be really slow, even causing an infinite loop as an extreme edge case.

Comment: This can easily get stuck in an infinite loop, `print(divisible_random(2,5,3))` @KocT9H

Comment: I agree about the option to get stuck in infinite loop. Extra protection should be added to the function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've added a counter to stop the loop and return (result // 4 * 4) in case counter is 0.

Comment: IMO, when you can extend already provided functions by `random` module in a single line, not worth the effort to keep choosing numbers in a loop and wasting cycle time!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing coming to my mind is creating a list of all the possible choices using [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in the given interval, followed by randomly choosing one value using  [choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

So, in this case, for a given `a` and `b`,

```
random.choice(range(a + 4 - (a%4), b, 4))
```

If `a` is a perfect multiple of 4, then

```
random.choice(range(a, b, 4))
```

Would give you the required random number.

So, in a single generic function, (as suggested in comments)

```
def get_num(a, b, x):
    if not a % x:
        return random.choice(range(a, b, x))
    else:
        return random.choice(range(a + x - (a%x), b, x))
```

where `x` is the number whose multiples are required.

Comment: I was about to post this. +1

Comment: The solution is wrong: `random.choice(range(5 + (5%4), 7, 4))` yields 6. It is also very inefficient.

Comment: @DYZ missed that, corrected now

Comment: You probably want to wrap this logic in a single function then...

Comment: I see that you took the approach `a+4-(a%4)` from my answer, please consider upvoting my answer @DivyanshuSrivastava :)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Nope, I didn't.

Comment: @DYZ: Since Divyanshu is wrong about `range` creating a list, the efficiency is actually fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) with a step size of `n`, using `a+n-(a%n)` as start if a is non-divisible by n, else use `a` as start

```
import random

def rand_n(a, b,n):

    #If n is bigger than range, return -1
    if n > b-a:
        return -1

    #If a is divisible by n, use a as a start, using n as step size
    if a%n == 0:
        return random.randrange(a,b,n)

    # If a is not divisible by n, use a+n-(a%n) as a start, using n as step size
    else:
        return random.randrange(a+n-(a%n),b, n)
```

Comment: Now what's wrong with this ?

Comment: wrong as below, e.g. if a=0, 0 is never chosen although acceptable.

Comment: Got an error def rand_n(a, b, 4):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are interchangeably using `n` and 4 in your function.

Comment: Still error. Let me fix it for you.

Comment: No issues, I fixed it, thanks for letting me know @DivyanshuSrivastava Please upvote if it works now for you :) –

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, your solution might produce out of range results, e.g. `math.ceil(15 / 4) * 4 == 16`. Also, be aware that the produced distribution might be very far from uniform. For example, if `a == 0` and `b == 4`, the generated number will be 4 in 80% of the cases.
Aside from that, it seems good to me, but in Python, you can also just use the integer division operator (actually floor division, so it's not equivalent to your examlpe):

```
result = random.randint(a, b)
result = result // 4 * 4
```

But a more general albeit less efficient method of generating uniform random numbers with specific constraints (while also keeping the uniform distribution) is generating them in a loop until you find a good one:

```
result = 1
while result % 4 != 0:
    result = random.randint(a, b)
```