# How Can I generate a Latin Hypercube Samples with different distribution in scikit-optimize?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sample

I use the [scikit-optimize library](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.sampler.Lhs.html#skopt.sampler.Lhs.generate) to generate LHS matrix. I would like to choose the distribution(uniform, normal, ...) for each parameter. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Scikit-optimize supports uniform and log-uniform distributions for integer and floats. More details in the docs: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.Space.html#skopt.Space. And some example use to create distributions can be found here as well: https://github.com/solegalli/hyperparameter-optimization/blob/master/Section-10-Scikit-Optimize/01-Search-space-distributions.ipynb

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71900217/6729710, however, it uses SciPy.