# A random number generator (Float)

Tags: python

I am using Blender, which it can incorporate python into it, and now I need a random float generator, no range, how can I do this? I have found ways, but it is with range.

Comment: What do you mean no range? There have ___got___ to be some bounds

Comment: I assume you mean, "I want a random `float` not a random `int`"... if so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range-python

Comment: u can use random.uniform()