# How to generate list of unique random floats in Python

Tags: python, random, distinct-values

I know that there are easy ways to generate lists of unique random integers (e.g. `random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)`).

I wonder whether there is some better way of generating a list of unique random floats, apart from writing a function that acts like a range, but accepts floats like this:

```
import random

def float_range(start, stop, step):
    vals = []
    i = 0
    current_val = start
    while current_val < stop:
        vals.append(current_val)
        i += 1
        current_val = start + i * step
    return vals

unique_floats = random.sample(float_range(0, 2, 0.2), 3)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Generate random ints, scale and translate.

Comment: `np.random.uniform` with a post-check probably?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is the correct place for this i think

Comment: But real numbers aren't finite.

Comment: @PeterWood There are certainly finite real numbers.

Comment: @Mitch I don't understand. The amount of real numbers between 0 and 1 is not finite.

Comment: @PeterWood Agreed, but that isn't what you previously said - perhaps a misunderstanding.

Comment: There is an infinite amount of real numbers between any two given reals (e.g. `start` and `stop`). Sampling that infinite number is probably not well-defined (how do you ensure each of those numbers has an equal probability of appearing in the result?). I think you would need to define an `epsilon` that limits the number of significant figures to make the function well-defined.

Comment: @logc Sampling from a continuous distribution is a _very_ well known problem. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling#Continuous_distributions).

Comment: What are you trying to do with your random floats?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range

Comment: Note that "unique" by definition is something other than "random".

Comment: @Shadur it depends what you mean. A random sample can be unique.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Answer

One easy way is to keep a set of all random values seen so far and reselect if there is a repeat:

```
import random

def sample_floats(low, high, k=1):
    """ Return a k-length list of unique random floats
        in the range of low <= x <= high
    """
    result = []
    seen = set()
    for i in range(k):
        x = random.uniform(low, high)
        while x in seen:
            x = random.uniform(low, high)
        seen.add(x)
        result.append(x)
    return result
```

### Notes

- This technique is how Python's own *random.sample()* is implemented.
- The function uses a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to track previous selections because searching a set is O(1) while searching a list is O(n).
- Computing the probability of a duplicate selection is equivalent to the famous [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).
- Given 2**53 distinct possible values from *random()*, duplicates are infrequent. 
  On average, you can expect a duplicate float at about 120,000,000 samples.

### Variant:  Limited float range

If the population is limited to just a range of evenly spaced floats, then it is possible to use [*random.sample()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#random.sample) directly.  The only requirement is that the population be a [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-sequence):

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import Sequence

class FRange(Sequence):
    """ Lazily evaluated floating point range of evenly spaced floats
        (inclusive at both ends)

        >>> list(FRange(low=10, high=20, num_points=5))
        [10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 17.5, 20.0]

    """
    def __init__(self, low, high, num_points):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
        self.num_points = num_points

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_points

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index < 0:
            index += len(self)
        if index < 0 or index >= len(self):
            raise IndexError('Out of range')
        p = index / (self.num_points - 1)
        return self.low * (1.0 - p) + self.high * p
```

Here is a example of choosing ten random samples without replacement from a range of 41 evenly spaced floats from 10.0 to 20.0.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(FRange(low=10.0, high=20.0, num_points=41), k=10)
[13.25, 12.0, 15.25, 18.5, 19.75, 12.25, 15.75, 18.75, 13.0, 17.75]
```

Comment: this is what i would recommend ... set lookup is O(1) ... and random float is easy

Comment: For the question in the title, yes. But for the actual question (which has a step size argument), the probability of getting a duplicate in a discrete set like that is not very small so I think @user2357112's suggestion is more efficient.

Comment: How better is this than simply `while x in result:`?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar: Looking up `x in result` takes time proportional to the length of `result`. If you made `result` a set, it wouldn’t be unsorted.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar ``while x in result`` does an O(n) linear search.  The ``x in seen`` approach does an O(1) search.  For a large value of *k* the performance difference is enormous.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you both for the answer, learned something today!

Comment: It is equivalent to the birthday problem with `n` being something like `(2^63)*100`. Unless something egregious would happen in the extremely rare case that duplicates occurred (which I can't imagine), I don't see why direct sampling from a uniform distribution wouldn't be fine.

Comment: @ayhan Nah, the step thing in the question looks like only his attempt to solve his problem, not like what he actually wants. Read his text about it.

Comment: @Mitch Where does the `*100` come from? You can't have a population larger than 2^64 when you represent the values with 64 bits (as Python's `float` usually are).

Comment: @Mitch The population is closer to ``2**53`` since double precision floats have a 53-bit mantissa.   But yes, the odds of reselection are very low.  That said the OP did specifically ask for login like *random.sample()* and for the values to be unique.  So this is the answer to the question as asked.  What should be done in a real application really depends on why you want unique floats, how you're going to use them, and the cost of a rare duplicate.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I took into account his example range, sorry a bit confusing - I was just guess-timating.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger And agreed! I don't know, I just get the impression 99% of people who believe they need "unique random floats" don't really need that "uniqueness", so I hope they don't get the wrong idea from this question/answer. Sampling without replacement from a continuous distribution isn't something I've ever come across - granted if you had a pathologically small interval it might be necessary for some reason.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Is it really 53? Not just 52? Because only 52 bits are explicitly stored. Actually I recently wondered how random floats are generated and failed to find out. Do you know how that's done?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Hmm, thought more about it. Aren't there 2^52 possible values in [0.5, 1)? And 2^52 more in [0.25, 0.5)? And 2^52 more in [0.125, 0.25)? And so on? The exponent goes from -1 for the interval [0.5, 1) down to -1023. So that's 1023*2^52 possible values even just in [0, 1), no? Meaning about 2^62.

Comment: The code is in Module/_randommodule.c in the *random_random()* function.  Essentially, it generates a 53-bit random integer and then multiplies by ``(1.0/9007199254740992.0)`` where the latter value is ``2.0 ** 53``.  The technique assures the random floats are equidistributed.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Awesome, thanks. Then you're obviously right, 2^53 possibilities. I still think it *could* use the above 2^62 but I guess people decided it's not worth it...

Comment: @StefanPochmann To go beyond 2^53, you need to use bits in the exponent.  That would cause the random floats to no longer be equidistributed.

Comment: I second what Mitch said:  I don't think the code to sample unique floating point numbers from a continuous distribution is ever useful.  If you are OK with floats being arbitrarily close together, but they can't be the same, you are likely making some wrong assumptions.

Comment: can I get a list of random floats in increasing or decreasing sequence ?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb The usual way is to generate the floats and then sort them.  This is used for example to model arrival times for customers.

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to generate IoT sensors data so they can increase gradually and decrease as well so sort thing will not work in this case.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb I recommend that you open a new question. Your question is almost completely unrelated to this thread.   Also, comments aren't the right place to ask questions.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily use your list of integers to generate floats:

```
int_list = random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
float_list = [x/10 for x in int_list]
```

Check out [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value) about generating random floats.

If you want it to work with python2, add this import:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: This will only work as intended in Python 3.x, because in Python 2.x it will do integer division. You could explicitly write `x / 10.` to make it work on both

Comment: @Graipher Thanks, added python2 compatibility

Answer (score 5):

If you need to guarantee uniqueness, it may be more efficient to

1. Try and generate `n` random floats in `[lo, hi]` at once.
2. If the length of the unique floats is not `n`, try and generate however many floats are still needed

and continue accordingly until you have enough, as opposed to generating them 1-by-1 in a Python level loop checking against a set.

**If you can afford NumPy** doing so with `np.random.uniform` can be a huge speed-up.

```
import numpy as np

def gen_uniq_floats(lo, hi, n):
    out = np.empty(n)
    needed = n
    while needed != 0:
        arr = np.random.uniform(lo, hi, needed)
        uniqs = np.setdiff1d(np.unique(arr), out[:n-needed])
        out[n-needed: n-needed+uniqs.size] = uniqs
        needed -= uniqs.size
    np.random.shuffle(out)
    return out.tolist()
```

**If you cannot use NumPy**, it still may be more efficient depending on your data needs to apply the same concept of checking for dupes afterwards, maintaining a set.

```
def no_depend_gen_uniq_floats(lo, hi, n):
    seen = set()
    needed = n
    while needed != 0:
        uniqs = {random.uniform(lo, hi) for _ in range(needed)}
        seen.update(uniqs)
        needed -= len(uniqs)
    return list(seen)
```

---

#### Rough benchmark

**Extreme degenerate case**

```
# Mitch's NumPy solution
%timeit gen_uniq_floats(0, 2**-50, 1000)
153 µs ± 3.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# Mitch's Python-only solution
%timeit no_depend_gen_uniq_floats(0, 2**-50, 1000)
495 µs ± 43.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Raymond Hettinger's solution (single number generation)
%timeit sample_floats(0, 2**-50, 1000)
618 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**More "normal" case** (with larger sample)

```
# Mitch's NumPy solution
%timeit gen_uniq_floats(0, 1, 10**5)
15.6 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Mitch's Python-only solution
%timeit no_depend_gen_uniq_floats(0, 1, 10**5)
65.7 ms ± 2.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Raymond Hettinger's solution (single number generation)
%timeit sample_floats(0, 1, 10**5)
78.8 ms ± 4.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: So the point is that *numpy* is faster than regular Python for numeric work?
 And that you think there should be a *numpy* answer to a non-numpy question?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger My point was moreso that if we have a fast way (i.e. `np.random.uniform`) to generate a whole bunch of random floats at once, it is faster to try to do it all at once and _then_ check for dupes than proceed one at a time with `random.uniform`. So yes, I'm not sure how much of a performance gain you would see using `random.uniform` in a list comp. and updating a set (maybe just less set checks). but I think this could be useful for someone?

Comment: Yes.  Cleaning out dups at the end works just as well.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I tried to flesh out my answer a bit to make the NumPy dependency more clear and added a Python example of what I was trying to say if I was talking in circles before :) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `random.uniform(start, stop)`. With double precision floats, you can be relatively sure that they are unique if your set is small. If you want to generate a big number of random floats and need to avoid that you have a number twice, check before adding them to the list.

However, if you are looking for a selection of specific numbers, this is not the solution.

Comment: If you're planning on checking for uniqueness before keeping a generated float, I would suggest using a set instead of a list to keep it O(n), as checking a list each time would make it O(n^2)

Comment: Assurance of uniqueness is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem , so being "relatively sure that they are unique" isn't sound once the number of selections grows sufficiently large.

Comment: with the number of floats searched given in the example, the risk of having double values is small. Nevertheless, you are right. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
min_val=-5
max_val=15

numpy.random.random_sample(15)*(max_val-min_val) + min_val
```

or use uniform

```
numpy.random.uniform(min_val,max_val,size=15)
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee uniqueness. Try for example `len(set(numpy.random.uniform(1, 1 + 2**-40, size=1000)))` and you'll get only about 887 instead of 1000.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation Python has the random.random() function:

```
import random
random.random()
```

Then you will get a float val as: 0.672807098390448

So all you need to do is make a `for` loop and print out random.random():

```
>>> for i in range(10):
print(random.random())
```

Answer (score 0):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) has a generic [`numeric_range`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=numeric#more_itertools.numeric_range) that handles both integers and floats.

```
import random

import more_itertools as mit

random.sample(list(mit.numeric_range(0, 2, 0.2)), 3)
# [0.8, 1.0, 0.4]

random.sample(list(mit.numeric_range(10.0, 20.0, 0.25)), 10)
# [17.25, 12.0, 19.75, 14.25, 15.25, 12.75, 14.5, 15.75, 13.5, 18.25]
```

Answer (score 0):

> random.uniform generate float values

```
import random

def get_random(low,high,length):
  lst = []
  while len(lst) < length:
    lst.append(random.uniform(low,high))
    lst = list(set(lst))
  return lst
```