# How do I generate random float and round it to 1 decimal place

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about generating a random float and then rounding that float to the nearest decimal point in Python 3.4?

Comment: random float between which and which values?

Comment: you can find the documentation under [random](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html) , [round](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: why can't you generate a random integer instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random number between a float range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri  Thanks for the retag. Good idea.  I'll just include that in my answer.  If you don't object.

Comment: @Simon Sure. Go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

You need two things: [The random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) and the builtin function [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#round).

First you need a random number. This is as easy as:

```
import random
a = random.random()
```

This will produce a number between 0 and 1.  Next use `round()` to round it:

```
b = round(a, 1) # Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger for the suggestion 
print(b)
```

The second argument in `round()` specifies the number of decimal places it rounds to in this case 1 which means it rounds to 1 decimal place.

and your done.

**Method 2:**

The other way you can do this is to use [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) this will produce a whole number within a range that we can then divide by 10 to get it to one decimal place:

```
import random # get the random module
a = random.randint(1, 9) # Use the randint() function as described in the link above
b = a / 10 # Divide by 10 so it is to 1 decimal place.
print(b)
```

and your done

Comment: You don't need to multiply or divide at all. `round` takes two arguments, where the second is the number of digits to round to, so you could just do `b = round(a, 1)`, which directly rounds to a single digit after the decimal in a single step.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a float between 0.0 and 1.0, you can do it with:

```
import random
print(int(random.random()*10) / 10.0)
```

(Note that the division is by 10.0 and not 10 to force the float operation)

Output:

> 0.2
>   0.6
>   0.8
>   ...

Comment: Won't `int` always round off?

Comment: Fixed now @Simon.

Comment: Notes: 1. The OP specified Python 3; `/ 10` will work just fine (because `/` is true division on Py3, not floor division). 2. This doesn't round to *nearest* decimal, it rounds towards zero (if you generated `0.99999`, `9.9999` would be truncated to `9`, then division  would get you `0.9`, not the closer `1.0`).