# How do I get k different random numbers between a float range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range) question which explains how to get one random number between a float range and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range) which explains how I can get n different random numbers which are integers.

I want k unique random numbers which are float and also the range is float.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: The only method that I could think of is making a function which generates the first random float and then when I generate the second random float, I check if it is same as the first or not. Similarly for the third, I check it for first and second. Repeat until I get 4 different values

Comment: Well, add that and the code to your question. Then, detail why this solution isn't sufficient for you. To be honest, a question asking for code always has the smell of homework, and you can avoid that by showing your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 :**

```
import random

def get_rand_array(lower_bound, upper_bound, total_nums):
    rand_set = set()

    while( len(rand_set) < total_nums ):
        rand_set.add( random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound) )

    return rand_set

a = get_rand_array(1.0, 1.2, 5)
print( str(a) )
```

In each iteration, generate a random number in the desired range and add it to a `set` which makes sure that every element in it is unique

**Method 2:**

```
import random

def get_random_array(lower_limit, upper_limit, total_nums):
    rand_array = []

    while( len(rand_array) < total_nums ):
        current_rand = random.uniform(lower_limit, upper_limit)

        if( current_rand not in rand_array ):
            rand_array.append(current_rand)

    return rand_array

a = get_random_array(3.0, 3.1, 5)
print( str(a) )
```

Instead of using `set` as in method 1, in each iteration, check if the `current_rand` is already present in `rand_array`; if absent, append it to `rand_array`, which ensures unique elements in `rand_array`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> n = 5
>>> a, b = 0., 10.
>>> [random.uniform(a, b) for _ in range(n)]
[1.1617037103617134,
 5.977376104342625,
 7.04027407732932,
 0.10349393354524894,
 2.3731423390045023]
```

---

If you're worried about uniqueness, you can compute the odd of finding a duplicate. It's given by [the following relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations):

[image: p(n,d) = 1 - e ** (-n**2/(2*d))]

Where `d` is [`2**52`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) and `n` the number of random numbers to be generated. For a thousand values, the probability is `1.11e-10`. That means you're 64 times more likely to become a millionaire with a [lottery ticket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EuroMillions#Prize_structure) than finding a duplicate in this list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier if you have numpy.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.uniform(1,100,10)
print(x)

[22.31472037 90.3789552  28.4565216  34.79490853 16.48289675 39.15659334
 15.63986831 24.15726628  3.0404023  16.43198165]
```