# How to define a variable which can assign any real number between 0 and 1 in python?

Tags: python, random

I want to define a variable s which can only take real values between 0 and 1 in python, how to write the code for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a random number between a float range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) library:

```
import random
s = random.random() # the default range is [0,1)
```