# Hello, someone can help me?

Tags: python, random

This program extract a random float numbers

```
import random
from time import sleep as z

print("benvenuti su random")
print("\ninserisci il valore minimo dell'estrazione")
min_var = float(input())
print("\ninserisci il valore massimo dell'estrazione")
max_var = float(input())
print("\ninserisci quanti numeri devo estrarre")
num1 = input()
print()
for i in num1:
    print(random.random(min_var, max_var))
    z(1.5)
```

But the terminal say me:

```
> line 13, in <module>
    print(random.random(min_var, max_var))
TypeError: Random.random() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

Some help?

Comment: The error says everything. Read the docs of [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random)

Comment: You might want [`random.uniform(min_var, max_var)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform).

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to Use `random.uniform()` for that.
So The Updated Code Would Be

```
import random
from time import sleep as z

print("benvenuti su random")
print("\ninserisci il valore minimo dell'estrazione")
min_var = float(input())
print("\ninserisci il valore massimo dell'estrazione")
max_var = float(input())
print("\ninserisci quanti numeri devo estrarre")
num1 = input()
print()
for i in num1:
    print(random.uniform(min_var, max_var))
    z(1.5)
```

This Question Is Almost Similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range)