# magicmock return side effect value between 2 values

Tags: python, mocking

I got a MagickMock and I want to return side effect values each times it is called. The amount of calls is not known. The return value should between 1 and 2. I was wondering how to do this, via Lambda function?

I was trying something like this:

```
patched.side_effect = lambda x: (1, 2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _What_ value between those? A random one (see the `random` module)? Incrementing from one towards the other? How you implement it is going to depend on what you actually want.

Comment: yes random, increment is not needed, just random

Comment: Then have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6088077/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. Any idea how to use the round(random.uniform(1,2), N) so it returns always a random when the mock is called? just side_effect = round(random.uniform(1,2), N)?

Comment: That would just be one random float, not a function or exception class/instance per https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try as below

```
>>>import random
>>>func = lambda x: random.randint(1, 2)
>>>val = func("")
>>>print(val)
>>>1
>>>print(val)
>>>2

patched.side_effect = func("")
```

only random module is enough to do same

```
>>>val = random.randint(1, 2)
>>>print(val)
>>>1
>>>print(val)
>>>2
patched.side_effect = random.randint(1, 2)
```