# Specific random number range

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, random

I want to generate random float number in the range 0 and 0.0001

I tried:

```
from numpy import random
random.random(0, 0.0001)
```

But i got the error :

TypeError: random() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)

Then i tried :

```
 from numpy import random
 random.random(0.0001)
```

But i got the error :
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

How can i produce random numbers in this range ? [0, 0.0001]

Comment: `random.random()/10000`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a random number between a float range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088077/how-to-get-a-random-number-between-a-float-range)

Comment: `np.random.random` docs specify only one argument, the `size`, number of returned values.  Range [0,1) is fixed.  When getting errors like this, your **first** stop should be the function documentation.  If it still isn't clear, then ask us :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use random.uniform like this

```
import random

print(random.uniform(0, 0.0001))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `random.uniform` to generate a float number between the given value.

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.random.uniform(0, 0.0001))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around this issue, you can generate a random number between 0 and 1 and divide the result by 10000.

```
from numpy import random
random.random() / 10000
```